# DataGrid and Cell-Level ComboBoxes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

### Scenario

ComboBox C depends on the selected value of ComboBox B, which depends on the selected value of ComboBox A.  All of these ComboBoxes are in a DataGrid.

Common Road Blocks:

1. The User must be able to add new rows (This Requires a ItemsSource item type that has a parameterless constructor).
2. To access the database to populate the List of Available Options for the Comboboxes, the current project would require the Database Credentials/DataContext be passed into the Constructor.

### Attempt 1

I've tried using 3 CollectionViewSources, one for each of the ComboBoxes ([Concept Code Here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387)), but the SelectedItem of the ComboBox gets automatically selected in the other DataGrid rows.  I need to find a way to isolate the CollectionViewSource to each row.

I've considered just adding the CollectionViewSource data to each of the DataGrid Items so I can just bind to it that way, but I have to access the database to generate the CollectionViewSource.

I also tried not sharing the CollectionViewSource as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159893/binding-with-collectionviewsource), but that destroyed the link between the 3 ComboBoxes, as well as the Rows.  If I could just set the CollectionViewSources to be shared within each DataGrid Row and not between each of them, I think it would work.  I just can't find a way to do that.

### Attempt 2

I've looked at this question: [How to get cell level ComboBox for WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843617/how-to-get-cell-level-combobox-for-wpf-datagrid)

This would work, but the User needs to be able to add rows to the DataGrid.  The example code in that question also uses a parameterless constructor.  I am in a situation where access to the database to populate the lists would have to be passed into the constructor.

### The Question

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to a `List` or `ObservableCollection`, not a `CollectionViewSource`

`CollectionViewSource` tracks the Current Item, so changing the value in one ComboBox will change it in all ComboBoxes

Comment: I need to track the Current Item so I know what to populate ComboBoxes  B & C with.  However, I do not want it to affect all rows.

Comment: ComboBox B populates based off of the CurrentItem in A and C populates based off of the CurrentItem of B.

Comment: @Paxenos The selected item should be tracked in your data object, not in your collection. For example, bind `ComboBoxA.SelectedItem` to `SelectedItemA`, `ComboBoxB.SelectedItem` to `SelectedItemA.SelectedItemB`, and `ComboBoxC` to `SelectedItemA.SelectedItemB.SelectedItemC`

Comment: Should the Collections to populate the ComboBoxes be kept in the data object as well?

Comment: @Paxenos No, those items seem static and should be stored elsewhere. Usually in this sort of case I will have a Static list of all my ComboBoxA items, and each ComboBoxA item will have its list of ComboBoxB items and so on. In the binding I will set the ItemsSource equal to the static list of items, and the `SelectedItem` equal to the item on the data object. The item on the data object is usually stored as a key, such as an integer, and a public property is exposed that returns the `StaticList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.key == DataItemKey)`

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, I should set ComboBoxB.ItemSource = to ((SelectedItemAType)SelectedItemA).BList?

Comment: Sure that would work, but you don't need the cast in your binding. Simply binding `ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemA.BList}"` should work fine. Also, I had my earlier comment mistaken. You should store the selected item B and C on the data object with A, not on the SelectedItemA object itself. `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemA.BList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemB}" />`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7061/discussion-between-paxenos-and-rachel)